# react-native run-android: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

When i create a new react-native app, firstly i build the gradle with android studio. After i run this command: `react-native run-android` and of course i get an error:
`Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0`.
So apparently, it is a react-native bogue...
So, in my gradle.wrapper.porperties file I changed the gradle version to 7.
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-all.zip`
And guess what? I got this error:
`Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0`
How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issues, looks like React Native in general is still migrating to Gradle 7.0, I guess we just have to keep using old Gradle build and wait unti migration ends :)

Comment: Please enrich your answer for new and unfamiliar users that might need extra guidance

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.